# Impala SQL left join on t1 vs t2

Tags: sql, cloudera, impala

I am having a problems with the join here and in specific the on x=y
IN SQL Impala, can somebody please help me understand how it works. The  `SUBSTR(cast(t1.employee_number as string), 3,10) as short_employee_number` works fine, I tested that, but as I am building this left join, I do not understand what ultimately should be in the on x=y
I tried

```
SUBSTR(cast(t1.employee_number as string), 3,10) =  t2.short_staff_number
t1.short_employee_number =  t2.short_staff_number
short_employee_number=  t2.short_staff_number
```

none of which worked.

What is the problem?

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
    SUBSTR(cast(t1.employee_number as string), 3,10) as short_employee_number, 
    t1.begin_date_it0001,
    t1.end_date_it0001,
    t1.cost_center
    t1.position,
    t2.local_time_createddate,
    t2.area,
    t2. unit, 
    t2.short_staff_number, 
    t2.alias, 
    t2.email

    FROM dataone  as t1 
    LEFT JOIN datatwo as  t2 
    ON 
    short_employee_number  = t2.short_staff_number ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

You can't use the `SELECT FIELDS` at the `FROM` but only at the `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    SUBSTR(cast(t1.employee_number as string), 3,10) as short_employee_number, 
    t1.begin_date_it0001,
    t1.end_date_it0001,
    t1.cost_center
    t1.position,
    t2.local_time_createddate,
    t2.area,
    t2. unit, 
    t2.short_staff_number, 
    t2.alias, 
    t2.email

    FROM dataone  as t1 
    LEFT JOIN datatwo as  t2 
    ON 
     SUBSTR(cast(t1.employee_number as string), 3,10)  = t2.short_staff_number ;
```